# Is it allowed to put a zero in the main diagonal of a Diagonal_matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

this question comes from that [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56728152/10731613).

svd a 5x4 matrix

$${\begin{bmatrix}
1& 0& 0& 0&\\
0& 0& 0& 4&\\
0& 3& 0& 0&\\
0& 0& 0& 0&\\
2& 0& 0& 0&\\
\end{bmatrix}}$$

gives U, $\Sigma$ and $V^T$

[wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=svd%20%7B%7B1,%200,%200,%200%7D,%7B0,%200,%200,%204%7D,%7B0,%203,%200,%200%7D,%7B0,%200,%200,%200%7D,%7B2,%200,%200,%200%7D%7D) gives the $\Sigma$ in this form

$${\begin{bmatrix}
4&0&0&0\\
0&3&0&0\\
0&0&\sqrt{5}&0\\
0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0\\
\end{bmatrix}}$$

NumPy gives the $\Sigma$ in this form

```
array([ 4.        ,  3.        ,  2.23606798, -0.        ])
```

both of the 2 tools put zero in the main diagonal of a Diagonal_matrix, is it allowed?

Comment: Yes; to be a diagonal matrix, you only require that all entries **off** the main diagonal be zero. The diagonal entries can be zero or nonzero. In particular, the zero matrix is always considered a diagonal matrix.

Comment: the original matrix has rank 3...

Comment: You seem to suggest that there are some reasons that this is not allowed. Would you please state any reasons or misgivings you have in mind?

Comment: @user1551 sorry, it's my misunderstanding. wiki says "a diagonal matrix is a matrix in which the entries outside the main diagonal are all zero", and I thought this suggest that the element in the the main diagonal should not be zero. I was wrong.

Comment: @Jay I see. Arturo's comment should have clarified things for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, is it allowed to put a zero in the main diagonal of a Diagonal_matrix.

neither [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonal_matrix) or the book "Introduction to Linear Algebra by Gilbert Strang" claim that putting a zero in the main diagonal is forbidden.